# Why do new lines appear when transforming polygon into lines?

Tags: qgis, polygon, line

I'm quite new to QGIS, and I want to do something fairly simple, but I found something strange in my data.

I want to transform polygons into lines, so I can apply the buffer function afterwards to the lines (that part doesn't come into play here).

However, when I convert the polygon into lines (using Geometry Tools), new lines appear that weren't in the original map (see red square in the attached image).

[image]

Does anyone know why this could be?

Comment: Dirty datasets, there are polygons you cannot see with this symbology.

Comment: @FelixIP Thanks! So I should trust the borders on the right?

Comment: Display originals as outlines only to see if this is the case.

Comment: @FelixIP The map on the left is the map loaded to QGIS just as I received it, so the original outlines would be the black ones shown in the left. The map on the right is after applying "Polygon to Line" tool.

Comment: As suggested, remove fill from the rendering style of your polygon layer. You may have more polygons than you believe because some large polygons cover small ones totally. For example your data contain both polygons of counties and municipalities

Comment: Thanks! That was the issue. I though because the data didn't have hierarchy I would see all boundaries of the polygons, but when I removed the fill I saw it didn't.